# Jsoup - passing raw body for POST

Tags: java, post, jsoup

I need to pass raw body to a POST request using Jsoup:

```
final Connection connect = Jsoup.connect(url);

connect.method(Connection.Method.POST);

String rawBody = // a JSON string representing JSON-RPC call

// fails here "Must supply an even number of key value pairs"
connect.data(rawBody); 

final Connection.Response response = connect.execute();
```

As I understand it expects pairs key,value. Is there a way to pass a raw body?

P.S. I already have code making HTTP posts via `HttpURLConnection` and wanted to upgrade to using Jsoup instead of relatively low-level code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem like it's possible. Connection#data is used for passing the parameters for the request, and parameters come in pairs.

Comment: It seems so. Though it's a very quick fix - just add `byte[] rawBody` property and pass it as is to the request output stream.

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky it is opensource, so you should be able to make that change yourself ;)